# Can TFS build agent bypass taking latest code from TFS server?

Tags: build, tfs, build-automation, tfsbuild

Can I any way bypass taking latest code for my off shore build agent while developing build server.
My TFS server is located in counter part location and taking latest code takes around odd 30 min.

While developing build server back here any change in script and re-run goes and take latest code. This is hurdle as it takes every time 30 min.

For now can I point my build agent to take the source code from local folder instead of TFS server.

Comment: If it is not taken from TFS server how you will get the latest changes in your build? So, don't you want the latest changes?

Comment: This is temporary for debugging build scripts. Once everything is up we will be taking latest as usual.

Answer (score 2):

On the "Process" tab of the build definition, specify "Clean Workspace: None". This way, the "Get Latest" will only get changed sources.

Comment: I could not find this option . Is this with TFS 2010?

Comment: Yes, I thought it was available with 2010. Did you open the build definition?  Did you see the "Process" tab?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [TFS Version Control Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248710%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the Build Server.

If you have a way of marking that build server as been off-shore (i.e. different location in Active Directory) then you can do that and the proxy should just work.

If not, you can force the build server to user the Proxy with an environmental variable on the Build Server like so:

```
TFSPROXY=http://mytfsserver:8081/
```